# Transferring conditional formatting to docs

Tags: google-apps-script

I have google sheet with student data, with the help of a script (third party), I am automatically creating student reports with information from sheets. The reports are produced as PDF, however a google doc template is set for the report.

All the data is merge fine. However, is there a way to include in the script conditional formatting. I have cell's which are set to different colours based on the value of the cell. However, during the merge to the report, the formatting is not being replicated.

Can someone advise of a code to use?

1) What I am trying to achieve is if in the 'AboveOnBelowTarget column, if it is "-" the cell changed to red, IF "=" the cell changes amber and IF "+" changes to bright green. When making the reports the script creates PDFs using a google doc template, I'd like the colors to transfer to the Doc template.

Please find the script [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1lM2sf34BadCIkvnuWfwIVlQEGYsNrMPH9o77Ye073rE/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you provide your current script? I think that it will help users think of your solution. Of course, please remove your personal information from the script.

Comment: You can create a script that reads the formatting of the cell and then use those values to perform some formatting on the document you generate, but that's not trivial, it takes some coding.

Comment: I have added my current code which I want to be updated for it to retain formatting in google docs.